# Python xlrd read as string

Tags: python, xlrd

I'm having difficulties in reading a particular cell value from Excel in xlrd. Whatever value I'm reading (date value) is getting converted to a number. I know there are solutions to convert it into a python date format, but can I read directly the string value in xlrd?

Comment: That's the way Excel works.  Sadly, many values are stored by Excel as numbers.   Please provide the details of the cell value you're reading in XLRD.  Print the cell type in particular and included it in your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

xlrd does NOT convert dates to float. Excel stores dates as floats.

Quoting from [the xlrd documentation](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dates.html) (scroll down a page):

> **Dates in Excel spreadsheets**
>
> In reality, there are no such things.
>   What you have are floating point
>   numbers and pious hope. There are
>   several problems with Excel dates:
>
> (1) Dates are not stored as a separate
>   data type; they are stored as floating
>   point numbers and you have to rely on
>   (a) the "number format" applied to
>   them in Excel and/or (b) knowing which
>   cells are supposed to have dates in
>   them. This module helps with (a) by
>   inspecting the format that has been
>   applied to each number cell; if it
>   appears to be a date format, the cell
>   is classified as a date rather than a
>   number.
>
> (2) ... When using this package’s [`xldate_as_tuple()`](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_tuple) function to convert
>   numbers from a workbook, you must use the `datemode` attribute of the
>   `Book` object.

See also the section on the [Cell class](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Cell) to learn about the type of cells, and the various [Sheet methods](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Sheet) which extract the type of a cell (text, number, date, boolean, etc).

Check out [python-excel.org](http://www.python-excel.org/) for info on other Python Excel packages.

Comment: I wonder how Excel knows when cells should be interpreted as dates -- it appears that xlrd is forced to guess.

Comment: @nobar: Excel has exactly the same information available as xlrd does. Both rely on introspecting the "number format.

Comment: Actually, excel files store a cell type in addition to each cell value. Each type is stored as an integer, which you can access in xlrd with sheet.cell_type(rowNumber, columnNumber). 0 is blank, 1 is text, 2 is a number, 3 is a date.

Comment: See https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html#sheet.Cell-class for more.

Comment: @Brian: Actually, excel files have no such thing. The 0 is empty (NOT blank), 1 is text, etc is derived by xlrd from information available in the file: for XLS files, floats are stored in NUMBER or RK or MULRK records, test is stored directly in LABEL records or indirectly in a shared string table accessed via LABELSST records, no record at all -> "empty", blank (formatted but no data) cells appear in BLANK or MULBLANKS records, etc. In XLSX files, the types are available in element attributes in the XML.

Comment: Ah, I've only been dealing with xlsx files and didn't realize xls didn't store that. Thanks for clarifying, John.

Comment: @Brian: ... and the types are NOT stored as integers in XLSX files. The possible values of the t (type) attribute of the c (cell) element are: n, s, str, b, e, inlineStr. They are more of how to unpick the XML element than what data type. The integers have to be derived, just as with XLS files.

Answer (score 7):

well, as you say:

```
# reading from a xls file (no .xlsx files, no writing!)
import xlrd  # install xlrd from  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook("YOUR_FILE.xls")  # xls file to read from
sh1 = wb.sheet_by_index(0) # first sheet in workbook
sh2 = wb.sheet_by_name('colors') # sheet called colors

# print all rows in first sheet
print "content of", sh1.name # name of sheet
for rownum in range(sh1.nrows): # sh1.nrows -> number of rows (ncols -> num columns) 
    print sh1.row_values(rownum)

# rowx and colx (x for Excel) start at 1!
print "row3 col 2:", sh1.cell(rowx=3,colx=2).value

col = sh1.col_values(0)  # column 0 as a list of string or numbers
print '"A" column content:' # python index 0, 1.colunm, called A 
for cell in col: print cell
print sh1.col_values(1) # 2. column, note mix of string (header) and numbers!
```

FOR THIS EXAMPLE THE XLS is:

sheet 1:listing

```
name            latitude longitude   status  color   date
Mount Hood      45.3736  121.6925    active  red     01-ene-01
Mount Jefferson 44.6744  121.7978   dormant yellow  23-sep-05
Three-Fingered  44.478   121.8442   extinct green   
Mount Washington 4.3325  121.8372   extinct green   
South Sister    44.1036  121.7681   active  red 
Diamond Peak    43.5206  122.1486   extinct green   
Mount Thielsen  43.1531  122.0658   extinct green   
Mount Scott     42.923   122.0163   dormant yellow  
Mount McLoughlin 2.445   122.3142   dormant yellow
```

sheet 2:colors

```
status  color
active  red
dormant yellow
extinct green
```

Comment: When i do a sh1.row_values(rownum) I'm getting list with the values already converted to floating point.

Answer (score 4):

Excel stores dates as numbers both internally and in .xls files and then formats them accordingly when displaying. Thus, if you read them naively with *xlrd*, you will get either numbers or strings. What you should do is check what the type of a cell is and then convert the number yourself. Either using *xlrd*'s built-in functions, such as `xldate_as_tuple()`, or your own function.

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739989/reading-numeric-excel-data-as-text-using-xlrd-in-python/2740525) for some more details.